# Ubuntu 21.10 - проблемы и зависания после обновления ядра до 5.13.0-23-generic

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, amd, xorg, wayland

Железо: ноутбук Acer Aspire 3 A315-41G-R0C7
ЦПУ: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
Системная память: 16 ГиБ

По умолчанию [Убунту 21.10 поставляется с ядром 5.13](https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-in-security-for-ubuntu-21-10)
У меня стояла версия `5.13.0-22-generic`
После вчерашнего обновления ядра до версии `5.13.0-23-generic` система стала хаотично подвисать/полностью зависать, элементы интерфейса накладывались друг на друга и бесконечно крутились в анимации, а загрузка стала занимать чрезвычайно длительное время, вплоть до нескольких минут.

Сначала я подумал, что проблема в графической оболочке. Как известно, в [Убунте 21.10 Wayland включена по умолчанию](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=54481), но возможность запуска Xorg сохранилась. На Xorg зависания были меньше, но всё же полностью не исчезли.

Обнаружив в системных логах ошибки по GPU и потратив некоторое время на поиски причин зависаний, я в итоге пришёл к выводу, что, похоже, проблема не особо распространена и в Сети почти нет никаких рабочих рекомендаций, а системные ошибки, видимо, оказались не связанными с проблемой. С чем может быть связана проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один [товарищ в комментарии к посту с похожей проблемой на Реддите](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/qbl81u/comment/hhdqbqo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) предложил обновить версию ядра до `5.14.14`, я воспользовался советом и это сработало. После этого я откатился к версии `5.13.0-22-generic` и всё работало также хорошо.
В итоге, как я понял, проблема действительно как-то связана именно с версией ядра `5.13.0-23-generic`.

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет.
Если есть какие-то другие идеи о причинах возникновения проблемы и их устранения - буду благодарен за информацию.